# How to make gqlgen dataloader Loader.Load(key) return a function that returns an explicit data type instead of interface{}?

Tags: go, gqlgen

I want to use `graph-gophers/dataloader` to implement a dataloader for bulk-fetching users.

I have implemented it like below but I need to return an **explicit data type**, not an `interface{}`

Firstly, I create `UserReader` with function `GetUsers` by given `dataloader.Keys`:

```
type UserReader struct {
    userCtrl user.Controller // This is my user service for Create, Get, Delete user
}

func newUserReader(userCtrl user.Controller) UserReader {
    return UserReader{
        userCtrl: userCtrl,
    }
}

// GetUsers return a list of result by given keys
func (reader UserReader) GetUsers(ctx context.Context, keys dataloader.Keys) []*dataloader.Result {
    output := make([]*dataloader.Result, len(keys))
    for i, key := range keys {
        userID := key.String()
        
        // Get list of user by string userID
        result, err := reader.userCtrl.GetUsers(ctx, userID)
        output[i] = &dataloader.Result{Data: result, Error: err}
    }

    return output
}
```

And then, I create a `Loader` with function `GetUser` to get a user by `userID`, it won't request data from `userCtrl` more than 1 time in a single request.

```
type Loader struct {
    userLoader *dataloader.Loader
}

func newLoader(userCtrl user.Controller) Loader {
    userReader := newUserReader(userCtrl)
    return Loader{
        // Create new user loader with batch function
        userLoader: dataloader.NewBatchedLoader(userReader.GetUsers),
    }
}

// UserLoader returns the user loader
func (loader Loader) UserLoader() *dataloader.Loader {
    return loader.userLoader
}

// GetUser return a user by given parameter
func (loader impl) GetUser(ctx context.Context, userID string) (model.User, error) {
    // FromCtx gets a Loader from context if it exists, else nil.
    ctxLoader := FromCtx(ctx)
    
    // Thunk is function return value with interface{} type and error
    thunk := ctxLoader.UserLoader().Load(ctx, dataloader.StringKey(userID))
    result, err := thunk()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result.(model.User), nil // Convert datatype here!!!
}
```

And finally, It can be use

```
dataloader.FromCtx(ctx).GetUser(ctx, userID)
```

But I need `userReader.getUsers` to return an object containing `model.user` not `interface{}` because I don't want to convert the data type in the `Loader.getUser` function.

Is there a way to have `dataloader.Result` return a certain data type instead of the `interface{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v7` version of `graph-gophers/dataloader` supports generics. Specifically, the [`BatchFunc` signature](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/graph-gophers/dataloader/v7#BatchFunc) has changed so you can specify the resulting type.